# Tableview with details

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a tableview with the data from an array. Now i want the details for all the rows of the tableview. If i select any recipe from the tableview it should show me all the ingredients and procedure to prepare that recipe with a pic of that particular recipe on top. I am new to this field so kindly help.

Here's "ViewController.m"

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
RecipeList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[RecipeList addObject:@"Chicken Kabab"];
[RecipeList addObject:@"Chicken Tikka"];
[RecipeList addObject:@"Chicken 65"];
[RecipeList addObject:@"Chicken Do Pyaza"];
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
RecipeTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
RecipeTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
RecipeTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
RecipeTable.delegate = self;
RecipeTable.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:RecipeTable];
[RecipeTable setScrollEnabled:YES];
[RecipeTable setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[RecipeTable setRowHeight:35];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return @"RECIPES";
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return RecipeList.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [RecipeList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;

}
@end
```

Comment: If I understand your question what you want here is to get details of the recipe you clicked in table view?

Comment: http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uitableview-loading-detail-view.html

Comment: @MeeraJPai yes exactly. i want that only with a picture of that particular dish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass recipe name to the detailViewController. Then depending on the name of the recipe you can load the suitable image in UIImageView.
In the code recipename is an NSString in detailViewController. Declare it as a property..

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSString *name=[recipe objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      detailViewController.recipename=name; 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Then in the detaiViewController.m

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        if([recipename isEqualToString:@"Pizza"])
         {
           UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"pizza.png"];
           [img setImage:image];
         }
        else if([recipename isEqualToString:@"Chicken 65"])
         {
           UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"chicken.png"];
           [img setImage:image];
         } 
    }
```

Comment: i have just pushed the view and have not used any image but when i am selecting the row its not going to the next view. can you guide me what is wrong.?

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSString *name=[RecipeList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.recipename=name;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    
}

Comment: thanks for the help bro... did some changes and its working fine... :)

Answer (score 0):

you must use the DidSelectRow Delegate of UITableView . Then if you select a recipe it calls the DidSelectRow delegate .Inside this delegate you do the coding for  pushing to a new ViewController . Create an UIImageView on top of your new ViewController , then pass the image from your TableViewCell to the UIImageView of your new viewController

Comment: you mean to say that for every recipe i should push a new viewcontroller?

Comment: use the same view controller but add different views on the view controller according to the recipe . Create a logic with switch statements .

Answer (score 0):

If you want the details of a particular Dish populated in another ViewController that is pushed, the easiest way is by creating an **NSObject** with all the details required for that particular dish and maintaining it as an array. When you select a row in tableView, the **didSelectRowAtIndexPath:** get the object at that indexPath and pass it to the next VC which is being pushed. In the detail VC you can populate the details with that from the object.

Instead of doing like this

```
  RecipeList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 [RecipeList addObject:@"Chicken Kabab"];
```

do something like

```
  RecipeList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 [RecipeList addObject:dishObj];
```

where dishObj is an NSObject, of Class Dish which contains Dish name, image and recipe.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    Dish *dishObject = [RecipeList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = dishObject.dishName;
    return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,
  you must use the DidSelectRow Delegate of UITableView

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

 DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
NSString *strDishName = [RecipeList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
detailViewController.strDishDetail =strDishName;
 // ...
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following tutorial will useful for u..[Segue](http://www.appcoda.com/improve-detail-view-controller-storyboard-segue/)